# How to acces to a model related to a user in DJango

Tags: python, django

I would like to access to a model related to a user in User. I know that it's possible to get the username or the name of the user using:  **request.user.get_username()**
**model.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):

  profile_user   =  models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  profile_note   =  models.CharField(max_length=30,...)
```

Is there any method to take the related model field without a query? 
Example: request.user.profile.profile_note

Comment: what prevents you from using `profile_user.username`  ?

Comment: Can you share the model name? When you say without a query, you mean without an additional query?

Comment: It's a bit unclear tho

Comment: You can access the reverse relationship on a `OneToOneField` using the model name lowercase, in your case probably `request.user.profile`? You want to avoid this additional DB query though?

Comment: I have the request and the user, but not the profile information so I would like, for example, take the user's profile_note taking as parameter the request itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `request.user` to always have `.profile` available without an additional query you can write your own [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) that uses `select_related` when looking up the user so that there is only 1 database query

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class ProfileBackend(ModelBackend):
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            return UserModel._default_manager.select_related('profile').get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'app.backends.ProfileBackend',
]
```

Now when `request.user` is loaded from the DB, the profile will be loaded in the same query. You can now access `request.user.profile.profile_note` without any additional queries

Comment: What should I put instead of `get_user_model()`? It's not defined

Comment: Added the import